# Can I use memory taken from a Macbook Pro in a Mac Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, memory, mac-pro

My Macbook Pro from around 2008 finally died. It has two 1 GB memory chips. (Specifically, two of this [Samsung chip](http://www.ascendtech.us/samsung-1gb-2rx8-ddr2-pc2-5300s-memory_i_ltpmemsam512mb8.aspx).) My question is: can I use these chips in my 2011 Mac Pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not directly.

[image: Image from laptopnews.ro at laptopnews.ro/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/dimm_vs_so-dimm.jpg]

The Mac Pro uses full-sized desktop DIMM modules, whereas the Macbook pro uses laptop-sized SO-DIMM modules. These cannot be directly swapped without a passive adapter, which I honestly wouldn't think makes much sense to bother with given how [inexpensive 2 GB of RAM is these days for a Mac Pro](http://ramjet.com/ItemDescription.asp?Item=MTP2G).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that doesn't really make sense. It was mostly me being sentimental. I think I'll just keep the SO-DIMM's around as a souvenir. Or perhaps I'll see if I can slot them into a Samsung Windows laptop I have... If that's not blasphemy!